# Wait for many web requests in a for-loop to return before calling function

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, networking

I have a `for-in` loop that makes a networking request for each item in the loop. I've done the digging and haven't yet found a viable solution. How can I wait until all requests have been returned before performing the next function?

I can't just call the function after the `for` loop because nothing will have returned before the function is called. I've tried `dispatch_group_enter/leave()` but it gets called after every single loop. I need to iterate through the entire loop, wait for each network return, and then fire the next function.

Is GCD still my best bet?

```
for item in array {

      let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

           if error != nil {

                   print(error)

           } else {

                   if let result = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as? NSArray {

                          if error == nil {

                                 print(result)

                          }
                  }
           }
     }
     task.resume()
}

// Call function here once I've printed every `result`.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an ideal solution, but have you considered calling another function from within each block, and keeping track of the number of downloads that are finished?  So if the following function is called each time a download is finished, for example:

```
func downloadFinished() {
    self.downloadsFinished += 1
    if self.downloadsFinished == self.array.count {
        // Do whatever you were going to do when all downloads are finished
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but there are a couple of `if` statements within the call, and it's never guaranteed that `self.downloadsFinished` would always equal `self.array.count.`

Comment: I don't see why this function couldn't be called anyway after each download - all it does is increment a value

Comment: Nice, it worked. I just have to be careful to not call `downloadFinished()` within an `if` block that may or may not get called, which was my original point. Thanks!